# Google Sheet comparative uppercase and lowercase

Tags: regex, google-sheets, array-formulas, uppercase, lowercase

I need to check the contents of a cell to make sure that all characters in it are uppercase, but comparative "=" `(=UPPER(cell)=cell`, doesn't work.

`"Abc" = "ABC" => TRUE`

`"abc" = "ABC" => TRUE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

`=EXACT(A1,B1)`

which will compare the case as well.

Answer (score 1):

regex is case sensitive too. try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B:B="",,REGEXMATCH(A:A&"", B:B&"")))
```

[image: 0]

or use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B:B="",,EXACT(A:A, B:B)))
```

[image: 0]